# Packaging a self-made service with dependancies — possible?

Tags: macos, applications, automator, homebrew, services

So I wrote a small service (a couple of services, really) which basically lets a user capture its screen (full screen or an area) and then make edits if necessary and then it uploads it directly to imgur and gives the user a direct image link.

I wrote it for myself but people at my workplace got interested and asked me to install it for them. Since my service has a couple of dependancies I basically had to borrow their Macbooks for like 15 minutes to install everything.

I wonder if it's possible to somehow pack everything so that I can hand it to other people who want to use it.

What my app consists of and what it requires:

1. A package from brew called imgur-screenshot (also available directly from github afaik)
2. A number of automator services that I wrote
3. A free image editor — Skitch
4. A config file for imgur-screenshot placed in ~/.config/imgur-screnshot/
5. Doing a couple of quick tweaks in system settings like assigning hotkeys to these automator services

I wonder just how much of these things I can bundle together and send as an archive or something to people who're not developers so that can do the installation in a couple of clicks. Also, how should I handle putting the config file into a hidden folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrote a bash scripted that bundled and installed everything in the end.